# Detect URl pattern

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have data collecting software.

Data: site visits/views.

So i have a lot views data: page url, date, visitor info.

Most of URLs is just different filters or something like. I.e URLs same but it have dynamic parameters.

For example:

- site1.com/?search=something
- site1.com/?search=some_word
- site1.com/?search=hello
- site1.com/?search=world

Should be "detected" as site1.com/?search={variable}

So that is a question:

Any algorithms to **auto-detect** patterns of URL?

Or some analyzing classes/functions? Any programming language.

Need solution that can process big batches of URLs.

**Wihout any manual pattern defining**(coz i dont know it and cant do it manually for many different sites).

UPD
For example:
I have many different URLs. From many sites. I dont know how these sites work. So i need to get for example 500 URLs from one site then compare and group it by common part to get 10 unique urls as result. Which should be automatically merged via replacing with {var} any dynamic URL parts.

Comment: _"Any algorithms to auto-detect patterns of URL?"_ What do you mean by "auto-detect patterns"?

Comment: What is "almost same"? Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think OP wants to go through URLs and find the static parts in them, e.g., all of them start with `site1.com/?search=` and then also find the parts that change, e.g., the search string.

Comment: I mean I have a lot URLs, some of them is almost same, but have dynamic parts. I want find dynamic parts in any URLs and group urls excluding dynamic part to get small amount of UNIQUE URls for each site.

Yes, @vlaz is right.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this :D

I see one probably way: just split urls by slash and/or parse parameters. Then compare it somehow and identify common parts for grouping.

But i have some really long URLs with 5-15 parameters, so its bit complicated.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't see how that relates. OP wants to detect which websites are present and what the constant part of them is, not just find the search parameters.

Comment: @vlaz Not clear, here, what "constant part" means?

Comment: @guest271314 if you look at the example, you will see - it's the URLs starting with `site1.com/search=` - this is constant, everything else changes.

Comment: @vlaz _"if you look at the example, you will see - it's the URLs starting with site1.com/search= - this is constant, everything else changes"_ This is solution, correct?

Comment: @guest271314 what, your suggestion? Because if so, no - you can have _any_ URL there and you won't know their structures ahead of time. Besides, the question you linked to is asking how to get a query parameter, doesn't give you what the base URLs are and doesn't even group them.

Comment: @vlaz Will delete link. Still do not gather Question, here. If you gather Question and expected result, perhaps post an Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't know the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some kind Proof of Concept :)

Example of splitting URL by "?"

- Parse parameters.
- Calculate frequency for unique parameter values.
- Get Nth percentile.
- Build URLs and replace parameters which frequency is more than Nth percentile

For small data like here in [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d7f33f7683f87f87a273b7d34b2333608709a54) 50 percentile is enough to group some URL.

For "big real data" 90-95 percentile.
For example: I use 90 percentile for 5000 links -> [result ~200 links](http://dsro.ru/gyazo/images/a24eef8d6bf60c4fb8ae766a45af.png)

```
<?php 
$stats = [];

$pages = [
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=123'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=123'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=123'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=321'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=321'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=321'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=qwas'],
    (object)['page' => 'http://example.com/?page=safa15'],
]; // array of objects with page property = URL

$params_counter = [];
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $components = explode('?', $page->page);

    if (!empty($components[1])) {
        parse_str($components[1], $params);
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            if (!isset($params_counter[$key][$val])) {
                $params_counter[$key][$val] = 0;
            }
            $params_counter[$key][$val]++;
        }
    }
}

function procentile($percentile, $array)
{
    sort($array);
    $index = ($percentile/100) * count($array);
    if (floor($index) == $index) {
        $result = ($array[$index-1] + $array[$index])/2;
    } else {
        $result = $array[floor($index)];
    }
    return $result;
}


$some_data = [];
foreach ($params_counter as $key => $val) {
    $some_data[$key] = count($val);
}

$procentile = procentile(90, $some_data);

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $components = explode('?', $page->page);

    if (!empty($components[1])) {
        parse_str($components[1], $params);
        arsort($params);
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            if ($some_data[$key] > $procentile) {
                $params[$key] = '$var';
            }
        }
        arsort($params);

        $pattern = http_build_query($params);

        $new_url = urldecode('?'.$pattern);

        if (!isset($stats[$new_url])) {
            $stats[$new_url] = 0;
        }
        $stats[$new_url]++;
    }
}

arsort($stats);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't get much out of a simple pattern, and have to write partially Complex algorithm something along the line of:

1. break each URI to it's parts: domain, page, Query-String (as keys-values)
2. group all URIs from same domain
3. if there is a page, group by that too. (most sites today use url rewrite rules so there isn't a real "PAGE")
4. here come the "hard part":

   - Match Query String Variables between the grouped URIs
   - if a Var is matching All(almost, all) uris, it might be meaningful to the content.
   - if all (almost) have the same value, it might be smth less meaningful...
   - note: you should also pre-check some common VarIds like: search, q,query, id,itemId, etc...

One last thing, today, as i mentioned, parts of the URL (aside from queryString) can infer dynamic parameters (e.g. Ebay items:  www.ebay.com/itm/9125483; www.ebay.com/itm/{itemId})

but hey, that's why you are paid for, to think about all those issues :p
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think what OP wants is regex, first you find the domain part in the url using regex, then you can remove the domain part and anything after the matched parts will remain (aka patterns).

for instance,

/^\w*.\w*(.\w*)?/\?search=/

will match the domain part in the url up to the ?search= part, then if you remove them from the whole urls you gonna get the pattern.

however i think it will match all domain-like strings in the url so you might want to change this so you don't remove the necessary part

edited for grammar and stuff

Comment: Not at all.
I have many different URLs. From many sites. I dont know how this sites works. So i need to get for example 500 URLs and compare and group it by common part to get 10 unique urls as result. Which should be automatically merged via replacing with {var} any dynamic URL parts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you're out of luck without using pattern matching. You could use a library, or someone else's code for now, but there are just too many variations to solve this problem otherwise. Try this on for size:

```
function getURLQueryString(url) {
    var query_list = {};
    var query_strings = url.match(/.*\?(.*)/)[1].split('&');
    var i, param;

    for(i in query_strings) {
        param = query_strings[i].split('=');
        query_list[ param[0] ] = param[1];
    }

    return query_list
}
```

You'll get back an object in which every key-value pair is a parameter from the query string.

Comment: (I can't comment above or I would have asked but) This is contingent on you already knowing this list of URLs, as well as the parameters they will accept in the query string. If you are unsure of which parameter is allowed, then you will need access to the server files to find out. Also, I'm assuming these are all GET requests